# How do I set refresh rate on each monitor invidually?

Tags: 16.04, monitor

What am I suppose to write to set each monitor on its own Refresh rate? I can write `xrandr -s 1920x1080 -r 144`  but that does apply on both monitors which makes my 60hz monitor go black.

Answer (score 0):

xrandr has `--output` option. You supply the screen's XID. Then it affects only the screen with the given XID instead of all of them.